# Difference between who is it to be blamed and who is to be blamed

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I was trying to learn the ways I can use blame and I got couple questions about it.

1. Is there any difference between "who is **it** to blame" and "who is to blame"?
2. what does "who am I to blame?" mean?

Is it like I know you did something wrong but I'm not even perfect so I can't blame you, or who should I put the blame on for the thing they have done?

Comment: 1) Yes. You should always assume that an additional word changes the meaning of the sentence; there are exceptions, but they are exceptions. The answer below is good one -- that's why I'm not providing an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Who is to blame? Whose fault is it? It is Johnny's fault.   Or: Johnny is to blame.

Who is to be blamed [by us, by them or some other agent in this passive]?

Johnny is to be blamed by the authorities for stealing the apple.